# Почему я не могу активировать виртуальное окружение?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

Я использую Windows 10 и cmder.
Алгоритм такой:

1. Установил `pip install virtualenv`
2. Создал папку для будущих окружений, назвал ее `environments`
3. В этой папке создал виртуальное окружение командой `virtualenv venv`
4. Активирую venv, с помощью команды обращения в этой папке  
   `/c/dev/environments/venv/Scripts/activate`

Но ничего не происходит ни ошибок, ни самого активированного окружения (venv), что я делаю не так?

Comment: В windows, вроде, активация происходит так: `%venv_folder%\Scripts\activate.bat`.

Comment: Активируется ли окружение при использовании обычной командной строки? Также попробуйте после активации из `cmder` выполнить команду `which python`. Если она укажет на Python в виртуальном окружении, то оно активировано. Просто вид command prompt не изменен.

Answer (score 0):

поменяйте символ '`/`' на '`\`'

```
D:\_Qt\Django-Stackoverflow>

D:\_Qt\Django-Stackoverflow>virtualenv venv

Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37'
New python executable in D:\_Qt\Django-Stackoverflow\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

D:\_Qt\Django-Stackoverflow>venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) D:\_Qt\Django-Stackoverflow>venv\Scripts\deactivate

D:\_Qt\Django-Stackoverflow>
```

Comment: Я уж не знаю с каких пор Windows отлично отрабатывает `/` в маршрутах. Для `/`, в отличие от '\', не надо помнить об эскапировании при использовании в скриптах, например, в Python. Я думаю, что Ваш ответ не решит проблему спрашивающего